# What is a "shower bath"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is a "shower bath"? I googled it but don't see how it relates to any military operations. From Hemingway's Farewell to Arms

> They poured me more wine and I told the story about the English private soldier who was placed under **the shower bath**.

Comment: It's probably an old-fashioned term, from the days when "showers" were a new invention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The narrator is talking about an occasion where a number of people told jokes. They were relaxing away from the war for a short while. Jokes are sometimes called 'stories'. The narrator told one about an English private soldier who was placed under the shower bath. A shower bath is another name for a shower, a thing that shoots water over you to get you clean. It does not relate to military operations. Neither does the story about the travelling salesman who arrived at five o'clock in the morning at Marseille when the mistral was blowing.